# pydev - call a function with only self as argument

Tags: python, pydev

I am new to PyDev, written scripts using mainly notepad++ and jedit where I never had these issues.
In a module, I have defined a function - get_user_inputs(self). I used the argument self as PyDev would not let me define the function othewise (and apparently it is the right thing to do).

Now my question is how do I call this function and what argument should I pass?
function(self) does not work and self.function does not work as well.

This issue I am seeing only in PyDev. In jedit and notepad++ I am able to execute same code with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `self` is only necessary for class methods. It doesn't make sense for normal functions.

That means you either omitted a vital information in your question or there is a bug in PyDev.

Comment: Actually I found out that in PyDev there is an option to ignore self argument in the class methods. If I choose that, this error is not present. I have defined a module in PyDev and defined this method. I have not created any class. So this should not be a class method. Is PyDev considering all the methods in a module as class methods by default?

Comment: @Sumod: It doesn't, at least not for me. Do you have a old/buggy version?

Comment: For some reason, it is working fine now. This is strange.All I did was this - Set the option to output error if self was not defined in class method in PyDev - Code Analysis - Others options. Then I closed the project and reopened it. Now I do not have the error and the program is running fine. Closing.